# Mysql Query Multiple Condition Error

Tags: mysql

i am stucking in a sql query that have to fetch data like one record from images and multiple records from contents with forgein key **place_id** only in one query.

example :

take place id 67.

data from images is

```
id   place_id     image

6      67      1444048037.png
```

data from contents is

```
id   place_id     image

4      **      **** 
5     **      **** 
7    **      ****
```

**Images Table**

[image]

**Content table**

[image]

Comment: what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT con.* FROM content as con, image as img WHERE con.place_id = img.place_id AND img.place_id = 67
```

Answer (score 0):

I can't test this right now, but:

```
SELECT place_id AS pImg FROM images, place_id AS pCon FROM contents WHERE images.place_id = pCon.place_id;
```

and use it like:

```
echo $row['pImg'];
```

Alternatively, you can use UNION, or JOIN

Comment: You should always declare join explicitely. this is a join at all but with an old an not used anymore syntax

Answer (score 0):

You can try this using UNION i think it will work for u.

```
(SELECT place_id, image FROM images WHERE place_id = '67'  LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT uid FROM content WHERE place_id = '67'  LIMIT 25000)
```